# In season 3 of ‘Ocean Girl’, why is Kal jealous of Jason?

Tags: ocean-girl

Why is it that Kal is jealous of Jason in the third season of *Ocean Girl*?

Is it because Neri loves Jason and cares more about him than about Kal? Is Kal expecting love or friendship from her? And is Neri even aware at this point that Kal is in love with her?

Comment: I’ve done my best to turn your question into legible English. In future, please DON’T SHOUT BY USING ALL-CAPS in your title, and please do try to give your question some structure by using paragraphs, proper punctuation and capitalisation, etc. They’re much easier to read that way.

Comment: Thank you Janus. i'm not expert person in English. so sorry for Caps. thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kal is jealous of Jason because Neri cares more for Jason than for him. From Season 3, Episode 14:

> Kal:  I don’t want to know about Jason.
>
> Brett: What’s wrong?
>
> Kal:  Neri,
>   worries about him.
>
> Brett: And your point is?
>
> Kal:  She likes him, more
>   than me. I feel… Bad. Do not understand.
>
> Brett: Don’t be such a wuss,
>   they’re just friends. Hey, here he comes now.
>
> Kal:   Neri will be with
>   him?
>
> Brett: Yeah sure, she always is. Hey, ease up. People will think
>   you’re jealous.

This may be because Kal sees her as his only friend, and does not want to share her with anyone else. This is especially true in light of Neri coming from the same planet as Kal.

From Season 3, Episode 17:

> Brett:    Come on, Kal. You can’t just stay down here forever. You’ve got
>   to get your head around it. Neri’s not just your friend. She’s
>   Jason’s, too, and mine, and…
>
> Kal:  Neri… My friend.
>
> Brett:    Yeah, but you can’t just own someone, Kal, and you don’t just
>   have one friend, I’ve got heaps.
>
> Kal:  Not me.

It's unclear whether Kal has a romantic interest in Neri, or is merely lonely.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
As per the attached pic "Neri keeping her head in Jason's arms." After Kal seen this he gets very angry. So I have to admit that Kal is expecting more than friendship from Neri.